# Is it possible to config string builder such way that append function will not convert data to string before append

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

StringBuilder doesn't append NULL , but if your object(which you want to append) is null it convert it to string and then append . Is it possible to change some configs that append function will not convert NULL to string ?

Comment: You can check the object is null or before you append to StringBuilder. If null, you can just append a empty string ("");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own **Utility** class for appending any values and check for `null` values before appending.

What `StringBuffer.append()` method does? There is no such config for this behavior.

Look into [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29) and mentioned below as well:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null) str = "null";
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0) return this;
    int newCount = count + len;
    if (newCount > value.length)
        expandCapacity(newCount);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count = newCount;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

null is not the same an an empty String. An empty String is still a String object.

From the documentation for [`StringBuilder#append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) method:

> The data is converted to a string before the append operation takes place

And

> Is it possible to change some configs that append function will not convert NULL to string ?

Overriding a method in a final class is impossible. And `append()` isn't a method in Object, it is in `java.lang.String`